# Rails Datetime not showing in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime

In my movies database I have a `release_date` column, and it my form there is this `<%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :release_date %>`. 
This works fine but how can I display the `release_date` in the movies show.html.erb

`<%= @movie.release_date %>` wont work, and so i dont know what else to use

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @movie.release_date.to_formatted_s(:short) %>
```

See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) for `DateTime#to_formatted_s`. This is the typical Rails approach. It takes other parameters and you can define your own date templates, this is all specified in the docs.

If Rails is not present, you can use [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) which `#to_formatted_s` is basically a wrapper for.

Comment: I get this error


undefined method `to_formatted_s' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Then your problem is that the movie's `release_date` is not set.

Comment: What do you mean? Its in my database and the model? And its a datetime

Comment: `@movie` is set, it finds the movie in the database, however, the column called `release_date` on the specific movie you're testing on, is not a date/it's not set. Thus it is represented by Rails as `nil`, not a DateTime object.

Comment: Ok, so how do I go by changing that? Making Rails see it is a date time object?

Comment: @user2225129 you will need to seeds and check what type `release_date` is. Also the answer to what @Sirupsen is a classic example of variable interpolation

Comment: There isnt anything in seeds? You mean schema? Well in the schema.rb it states that it is a datetime

Comment: You seem to be mixing up type and value. The type, datetime, of the release_date is probably right. The problem is, that whatever entry you are getting down from the database, whatever is in `@movie` in your test, e.g. if you're on `/movie/21`, it'll be the movie with id 21. That movie's datetime field called `release_date` is NOT set, thus it is not a date and Rails interprets it as `nil` which is "nothing" in Ruby.

Comment: So what is in the form? "<%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :release_date %>" ??

Comment: Your bug is somewhere else, specifically wherever you're setting the `release_date` for a single movie.

Comment: Sorry this is just so complicated

I create a migration to add it to movies table then added to the model then ran rake db:migrate then added it to the form and view, I honestly dont see where i went wrong, ive added migrations before and they've worked fine, what is it with the Datetime?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. How are you testing this? Which URL are you at?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30701/discussion-between-user2225129-and-sirupsen)